# Remove frequencies from periodogram

Tags: python, periodogram

I have radial velocity data (time, radial velocity amplitude, error). I want to find a periodicity of those data points for which I'm using the Generalized Lomb-Scargle method (https://github.com/mzechmeister/GLS.git). Below is the periodogram I received using this code. As you can see, there are two peaks, one at frequency 0.10633 and another at 0.2205.

Now I want to remove the signal of these frequencies one by one from the periodogram to check whether they are affecting each other or not, but I am not able to understand how.

Here is a link to the data file if needed: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYMnmJwSkTmRbIMPlb4V_hd7v0gKBTiD/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=103073202649979440695&rtpof=true&sd=true)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean *to see if they are affecting each other or not*?

Comment: BY removing one of the frequencies, the other peak will remain there or not. Also how the whole signal will get affected by removing that frequency.

Comment: But that is not the issue here (that is a part of astronomy and, I will check that letter on) the important part is how can I remove that signal.

Comment: Possibly by using best fit sinusoidal signal subtraction, not sure though.

Comment: Ok that's what I was afraid of. That's not how this works. Removing the fundamental doesn't remove the harmonics. you need to think about what you're doing here. You have a signal that's already been generated and sampled. If any frequency component $\zeta_1$
 had any influence on another $\zeta_2$, that's done. You can remove $\zeta_1$
 but $\zeta_2$
 will remain. Just like if you put a colored shirt in with your whites, your white socks will come out off-white. Getting rid of the colored shirt after the fact won't magically make the socks white again.

Comment: To answer your question, you can remove narrow-band frequency components using [notch filters](http://www.isle.illinois.edu/speech_web_lg/coursematerials/ece401/fa2020/slides/lec14.pdf).